# Jekyll not showing the same pages in _site folder as compared to running it locally

Tags: jekyll

I am new to making website using jekyll. When I run the website on local server using jekyll serve, it runs perfectly. I used jekyll build to build files for FTP server. Problem is the pages built in _site folder are without themes and images shown while running it locally.What can be its solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize and **override** your CSS styles, images or pages in Jekyll. That's why theme changes are not applied and "Jekyll Serve" command resets your changes.

- Look at this **Official Github Help** page: [Customizing CSS and HTML in your Jekyll theme](https://help.github.com/en/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme)
- And **Tom Kadwill**'s Page [How to Override CSS Styles in Jekyll](https://tomkadwill.com/2017/12/16/how-to-override-css-styles-in-jekyll.html)

Answer (score 0):

Locally, your site is served at http://127.0.0.1:4000/ which the root.

Your **_config.yml** `baseurl: ""` is empty.

Once you publish you site from something else than the root, say, https://example.com/blog/,  you need to check two things :

- that your `baseurl: "/blog"` is set accordingly to path.
- that you call your resources using `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` or with filter `{{ image.url | relative_url }}`